# KMP Project UI + Logic | Firebase

Tags: firebase, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I started a new KMP project using the Kotlin Wizard and tried to set Firebase but in iOS there are some issues. On Android the App is running.
First I added dependencies manually using "Add Packages..." and did not work. Xcode was not able to find the Firebase libraries.
Then, I tried with CocoaPods but it shows an issue with FBLFutures. I could not find an answer, some people comment an issue with arm64 architecture. Anyway, I was able to use the firebase libraries.
Finally, I started a new project using the Wizard just to set Firebase, I installed CocoaPods only with the Firebase dependency and shows composeApp/"env pod install" error.

This is my Gradle config

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "1.8"
            }
        }
    }
    
    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = false
        }
    }

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        version = "1.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "17.0"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
        framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = false
        }
        pod("FirebaseFirestore", linkOnly = true)

    }
```

My PodFile

```
target 'iosApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  platform :ios, '17.0'
  pod 'composeApp', :path => '../composeApp'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore'
end
```

So, I am not sure how to create a KMP using Firebase and works for iOS, because for Android there are no problems.

Someone that successfully set Firebase recently can help me? Please